# What is the precise relation between the category Set and the category Grpd?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, topos-theory

In [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Set) we read:

*Set is the discrete object classifier in the category Grpd of groupoids and functors.*

But this is far above my head, could you say in more simple terms what is the relation? Set is a subcategory of Grpd? Set is an object of Grpd?

Comment: Set is a full subcategory of GPD by considering the totally disconnected groupoid associated to a set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wording of the nLab article was confusing (and arguably incorrect). What was meant is that the [core groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/core+groupoid) of the category of sets is the discrete object classifier in $\mathbf{Grpd}$. Explicitly, the core groupoid is $\mathbf{Set}_{\text{bij}}$, the category of sets and bijections, which we view as an object of $\mathbf{Grpd}$. The wording in the article has since been updated to clarify this.

Comment: Very clarifying indeed! Thanks! How is this related to the comment of "julio_es_sui_glace" above?

Comment: @user234212323: it's true that the category of sets and *functions* may be viewed as subcategory of the category of groupoids and functors, by viewing each set as a discrete category (hence trivially a groupoid), but this isn't relevant for the consideration of the discrete object classifier.